# What is the exact way of Firebase (3.2.0) Querying with Swift (2.0)?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to query through my firebase database by using their guides but I'm unable to return results appropriately.
If someone can point out what I'm doing wrong or correct me, it will be very helpful.

Here are my code snippets

```
let ref = DataService.dataService.BASE_REF
    let myQuery = (ref.child("testing")).queryOrderedByKey()
    let MyQuery1 = (ref.child("testing")).queryOrderedByValue()
    let MyQuery2 = (ref.child("testing")).queryEqualToValue("Alphaa")
    let MyQuery3 = (ref.child("testing")).queryEqualToValue("Alphaa", childKey: "Alpha")
    myQuery.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot in
        print("Ordered By Key")
        print(snapshot.value)
    })

    MyQuery1.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot in
        print("Ordered by Value")
        print(snapshot.value)
    })

    MyQuery2.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot in
        print("Value Equal")
        print(snapshot.value)
    })

    MyQuery3.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot in
        print("Ordered by Value & Key")
        print(snapshot.value)
    })
```

Here is the result screen
Both order by key and Value don't sort it out.

```
Optional({
    Alpha = Gammaa;
    Alright = 24;
    Beta = Betaa;
    Delta = Deltaa;
    Epsilon = Epsilonn;
    Eta = Etaa;
    Gamma = Alphaa;
    Iota = Iotaa;
    Lets = 3;
    Okay = 1;
    Theta = Thetaa;
    Zeta = Zetaa;
    beep = 4;
    boop = 11;
})
```

Both Value Equal & Ordered by Value & Key give me Optional(null)

JSON table values

```
"testing" : {
    "Alpha" : "Gammaa",
    "Alright" : 24,
    "Beta" : "Betaa",
    "Delta" : "Deltaa",
    "Epsilon" : "Epsilonn",
    "Eta" : "Etaa",
    "Gamma" : "Alphaa",
    "Iota" : "Iotaa",
    "Lets" : 3,
    "Okay" : 1,
    "Theta" : "Thetaa",
    "Zeta" : "Zetaa",
    "beep" : 4,
    "boop" : 11
  }
```

I'm trying to return equal values or sort it from the server end instead on the client end.

Comment: can you give us the json on which your are testing ? it will be easier for us to see .. (the firebase tree )

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to put that up, i have done that now :)

Comment: Well, to start with, the queries are not really set up to match your data structure. Also, queryEqualToValue("Alphaa") will have no result as there no 'testing' nodes equal to 'Alphaa' - you could query for /testing/Alpha is equal to Gammaa with a deep query though. If you can clearly lay out what the expected result is for each query or what you are trying to accomplish we could better formulate an answer.

Comment: @jay I'm trying to convert sql type queries like select * from table where id='4'. I fixed my other two queries above, the only challenge remaining is finding by value or key or both.

Comment: You wouldn't need to query for a key as is you had the key, you could observe the node directly. i.e. key = 'testing', then you could observeSingleEventOfType on the /testing node. No need for a query. To query for a (child) value, you would need to define which child and what value. You may want to go back through the Firebase guide in Retrieving data so get some clarification on queries and observes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I continued testing and changed the way i would get my result by

```
 MyQuery1.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {
            snapshot in
            print("************")
            print("Ordered by Value")
            for snap in snapshot.children {
                print(snap);
            }
        })
```

this gave me the result i wanted for values :D and also for keys

```
Ordered by Value
Snap (Okay) 1
Snap (Lets) 3
Snap (beep) 4
Snap (boop) 11
Snap (Alright) 24
Snap (Gamma) Alphaa
Snap (Beta) Betaa
Snap (Delta) Deltaa
Snap (Epsilon) Epsilonn
Snap (Eta) Etaa
Snap (Alpha) Gammaa
Snap (Iota) Iotaa
Snap (Theta) Thetaa
Snap (Zeta) Zetaa
```